# Mutilated PCB - DRAM solder pads gone/bridged. Repairable?

Tags: pcb, repair, ram, damage, pad

I was attempting a DRAM upgrade with a heated plate and hot air rework station. I probably went overzealous on cleaning this area with the copper wick, and it seems to have sanded or scratched the PCB.

Edit with more information (earlier provided in comments below) because this thread was closed:
The motherboard is a Compal GPR31 LA-J481P from a HP Envy 13 laptop. Memory chips are DDR4 Samsung K4AAG165WA-BCWE. I have successfully completed similar projects before without running into this issue. Comments like "just take it to a professional" are not in line with the spirit of this website. Whether DDR4 ram has internally bridged or redundant pads as designed is not a common sense accessible fact that should be taken for granted.

There appears to be 3 solder pads gone, and 2 of them seem permanently bridged. I can't remove that bridge no matter what I use.

I'm not optimistic but just wanted to confirm - is this salvageable?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the bridge is supposed to be there on PCB copper trace, but you just scratched off the solder mask, as is shown on multiple other traces? Also regarding the missing pad, was there ever a pad to begin with, what does the memory chip side looks like, or is it an unused pin so it does not need a pad and the pad, if it ever was there, had no connections? Which board that is and why it would need an memory upgrade by replacing chips? What memory chips those are to find the data sheet?

Comment: *I probably went overzealous on cleaning this area* You went overzealous with heat, everything else is secondary to that. The poor thing got scorched. In the future if you want to do such upgrades, it's best to send them to qualified people who will do it for a reasonable price and give you back a board that looks like it came from the factory. I would gladly recommend STS Telecom in Florida - I'm a happy customer of theirs. Jason has a bunch of videos on YouTube that can teach you a thing or two about how to do it correctly next time if you wish :) STS takes overseas jobs no problemo.

Comment: As for whether it's repairable: sure, it is repairable, but I'd give it rather low odds if you were to continue working on it. At this point it is a job for an expert. By mutilating it beforehand, you've just upped the cost to fix it though. Live and learn I suppose - but a very common theme among the people who do modern board- professional level repair of consumer devices. Everyone thinks they are a cowboy until they fall off the saddle several time and then the pros have to take over.

Comment: **Important lesson for people who never did it before: Never, ever, attempt to repair the thing you want repaired first. Get some junk boards to practice on, and watch how the pros do it to give yourself a reference of what outcome you should aim for.** Getting a board like that repaired properly takes dozens of hours of practice for a novice with decent manual skills and a modicum of intellect.

Answer (score 1):

The solder bridge can easily be fixed (a bit bit of flux, then heating it with the soldering iron. If need be using solder wick or unsoldering pump).

The missing pads will be far, far more difficult.

For components that are not ball grid array (i.e. pads on the side), it is usually possible to scratch of the varnish from the track, and then solder a very thin wire between the track and the pin of the component. It already requires some skills.

With ball grid arrays, you obviously can't do this. There might be a way by adding a very thin piece of copper that you solder to the track (probably after gluing it to the PCB), then you solder your IC to this piece of copper. I have never heard of it being done, but I think it might be feasible. But this would be expert repair work. No idea how expensive your board is. If it is really expensive, try to contact some very good repair technicians and ask if they can do this. You could also try PCB assembly houses (I usually go to my PCB assembly house when I have PCBs needing tricky repairs or modifications).

Comment: Honestly, don't spend time trying to remove the bridge : whoever is capable of repairing the missing pads will have no problem removing the bridge. The critical part is restoring the missing parts, and that will not be easy work : I would strongly suggest you look to someone very experimented in PCB repairs.